# как исправить код с onClick

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код который не правильно работает и я не вижу где и какая есть ошибка в коде, код вообще не выводит ничего по нажатию кнопки, но он должен выводить простое ли это число или нет.

```
<html>
<body>

<script>
 Function isPrime() {
let num = document.getElementById("12-2_1").value
for (var i =2; i < num; i++)
if (num % i === 0) return false;
return num > 1;
};

let num = (isPrime() == false) ? 'Число простое': 'Число непростое'
document.getElementById("out-13").innerHTML = num
</script>

<font>Введите число</font>
<input type="number" id="12-2_1">
<input type="button" value="Результат" onClick="isPrime()">
<font>Результат</font>
<div id="out-13"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Буду благодарен за готовый код.

Comment: Когда не знаешь наверняка где ошибка - попробуй отладку (ссылка выше) + смотреть в консоль на ошибки (опять же всё написано в ссылке выше)

Comment: и обрати внимание, что `Function` !== `function`